# Executing .sh (bash scripts) via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, bash

Is it possible to directly execute a .sh file residing on the serverside from ajax on the client side? Or would I need to make a program in a server language (e.g. php) that runs the bash script, then have the ajax run the php?

Thanks

Comment: you can execute any program/script or server side , what is the issue ?

Comment: Is it possible for me to directly execute a bash script with ajax (e.g. they click a button and the server starts). Or do i need to create a php file that runs the bash, and then run the php file with ajax?

Comment: you don't need the php , just make sure your script sends the correct header followed by contents.

Answer (score 0):

With PHP you can use `exec()` method to run you .sh file.

Pass the name of the script via post data, but be very very careful, user can modify the param to execute malicious code on your machine!

Answer (score 0):

Put the sh file in a folder where apache has permission, and then use the command **exec(path_to_file)**.
Get more information and parameters here: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.exec.php.
 
But pay attention, it's safe mode in php is active exec will not work.
And make sure that no variable via request will pass the commands for this feature. As a security notification. ;)